# Catalog of keyboard shortcuts

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, desktop-environment, desktop

Is there anything remotely like a catalog of all keyboard shortcuts used by Linux applications?

I work with [AutoKey](https://github.com/autokey/autokey), an X11 desktop automation application that allows various desktop tasks to be completed by automatically generating keyboard and mouse events with scripts.

One of the main ways to activate a script is to assign a hotkey combination (keyboard shortcut) to it which triggers it to run.

The problem is that desktop environments (DEs) and many application programs also use hotkeys and assigning a new one with no conflicts is largely a matter of prior experience and trial and error. Unexpected things regularly occur when AutoKey "masks" a hotkey used by something else or another higher priority program such as a DE sees and consumes the hotkey before AutoKey even sees it.

It would be great if there was some magic program or database that you could ask if a hotkey combination was already used by something else.

AFAIK, there are no standards as to hotkey assignments and solving this is probably a very difficult problem because many hotkeys are only assigned when a particular program is running or its window is in focus and applications don't generally publish (in software as opposed to documentation) what hotkeys they honor and the details are often buried in source code or application binaries.

I don't think there is a solution to this short of some fancy AI/ML program that would learn as it goes, but I thought it was worth asking because this is a general problem for many applications that support hotkeys/shortcuts.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Keyboard_input) or [this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Interception-tools) can help a little.

Comment: @schrodingerscatcuriosity Thanks. Those allow changes to the keyboard functionality which isn't the issue here. I hadn't seen interception-tools before and I may have other uses for that.